# How to modify strings in an array using iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to iterate through an array `@idea_benefit` which looks like this:

```
["happier_customers", "happier_employees", "increased_revenue", "happier_customers", "decreased_costs", "happier_customers", "increased_revenue", ]
```

I need its elements to be humanized and capitalized like:

```
["Happier Customers", "Increased Revenue", ...]
```

I tried this:

```
@idea_benefit = []
@evaluations.each do |eval|
  @idea_benefit << eval.benefit
  @idea_benefit.flatten
end
@idea_benefit.each do |benefit|
  benefit.gsub("_", " ").capitalize
end
```

but I could not target the individual strings. How do I make this work?

Comment: `but I've been unsuccessful targeting the individual strings` could you please elaborate that part with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@idea_benefit =
@evaluations.flat_map(&:benefit).map{|e| e.gsub("_", " ").capitalize}
```

Comment: Beautiful.  This does only capitalize the first word though (i.e. "Increased revenue" instead of "Increased Revenue").  Is there a way to capitalize both?

Answer (score 7):

In Rails, you can do it using [`humanize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-humanize) and [`titleize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-titleize).

```
a =  ["happier_customers", "happier_employees", "increased_revenue", "happier_customers", "decreased_costs", "happier_customers", "increased_revenue" ]
a.map { |string| string.humanize.titleize }
# => ["Happier Customers", "Happier Employees", "Increased Revenue", "Happier Customers", "Decreased Costs", "Happier Customers", "Increased Revenue"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Enumerable method `map`.

```
@idea_benefit = []
@evaluations.each do |eval|
  @idea_benefit << eval.benefit
  @idea_benefit.flatten
end

desired_output = @idea_benefit.map do |benefit|
  benefit.gsub("_", " ").capitalize
end
```

The `map` method operates on each element of an Enumerable object (an Array, in your case) and returns a new Enumerable.  The block could be multiple lines if you needed; the return value of the block (usually the result of the last line) is what goes in the new array.

Comment: this gives me the error `undefined method `gsub' for ["happier_customers", "happier_employees", "increased_revenue"]:Array`

Comment: I'm assuming you've already flattened the array. I edited in the rest of your code to make it a little clearer.